# Why my Spark canot read data from Hive table while I can see these data in Hive?

Tags: database, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I want to use the data from HIVE, so I run code in Spark:

```
q = ("select * from sog_l1screen.dw_L1_newsdetail_orc_dt where dt='20170805' limit 10 ")
spark.sql(q).show(10)
```

And get error:

```
    17/08/16 08:12:22 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9, ip-10-86-199-137.ec2.internal, executor 3): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 33
    at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1004)
    at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderFactory.getSchemaOnRead(RecordReaderFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderFactory.createTreeReader(RecordReaderFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.<init>(RecordReaderImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.rowsOptions(ReaderImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger$ReaderPair.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger$OriginalReaderPair.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getRecordReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1113)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/08/16 08:12:22 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 318, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o174.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 12, ip-10-86-199-137.ec2.internal, executor 3): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 33
    at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1004)
    at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderFactory.getSchemaOnRead(RecordReaderFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderFactory.createTreeReader(RecordReaderFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.<init>(RecordReaderImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.rowsOptions(ReaderImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger$ReaderPair.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger$OriginalReaderPair.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getRecordReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1113)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1675)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1664)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 33
    at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1004)
    at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderFactory.getSchemaOnRead(RecordReaderFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderFactory.createTreeReader(RecordReaderFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.<init>(RecordReaderImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.rowsOptions(ReaderImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger$ReaderPair.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger$OriginalReaderPair.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getRecordReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1113)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

But when I run this SQL in my Hive, I can find these data.
I try to find the reason, and find that if `dt>=20170724` then I will get this error, if `dt<20170724`, I can touch the data. It is no reasonable since I can touch all these data in Hive, and I store these data in the same way, `partition by dt`.  And other tables in Hive do not have this problem.
Why this happen and how could I get my data ?

Comment: Can you please check if you have hive-exec-*.jar in spark/lib directory ? and is it different than one from hive/lib directory?